# How can I continually update when UISlider is past a certain value?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I'm implementing a UISlider that allows users to select a position on a football field.  The idea of the slider is for the field to scroll forward when the slider value is above a certain value (the section with the arrow).

My issue is that I can only respond to the slider on UIControlEventValueChanged - so the field will only scroll forward when the user is actually moving the slider.  I'd like it to move forward as long as the value is above a certain amount.

Any idea how I can do this?  (I'm open to any suggestion, including an implementation that does not use a UISlider, composite implementations, etc.).

Here's the implementation:

[image: The playYardageSlider]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to handle this is with a timer. Add an NSTimer instance variable to your class, named—for the sake of the example below—`moveTimer`, then set up something like this:

```
- (void)sliderChanged:(UISlider *)slider
{
    if(slider.value > 5)
    {
        if(moveTimer == nil)
        {
            moveTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self action:@selector(move) repeats:YES];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(moveTimer != nil)
        {
            [moveTimer invalidate];
            moveTimer = nil;
        }
    }
}

- (void)move
{
    // update the background behind your slider
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for me:

```
    [self performSelector:@selector(sliderMoved) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
```

I call the sliderMoved method after every 0.5 seconds when slider.value > 0.5.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the `continuous` property of the slider to YES.

Comment: No, that didn't work.  The issue is that I need to continuously redraw the background in the next view cycle as long as slider.value > threshold.  So the slider shouldn't have to be moving.

Comment: It says my reputation isn't good enough to answer my own question yet, but here's a solution I found that works:        [self performSelector:@selector(sliderMoved) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

I call the sliderMoved method after every 0.5 seconds when slider.value > 0.5.